# Archiving data from table in production db to same table in secondary archive db

Tags: sql

Hello I was ask to archive some tables in a sql db last week, I new to SQL I see some code in other questions.  Can anyone explain the what the declare @nextid table and the UniqueID int the follow code, the code is not mine and credit is given to the owner.

In my case  I have a primary key call attachmentID, in a table called attachments in a db call prod, the column for the date is attachmentdate.  I can not sure if I am to replace the UniqueID or what?  Please help if you can.

```
DECLARE @NextIDs TABLE(UniqueID int primary key)
DECLARE @ThreeYearsAgo datetime
SELECT @ThreeYearsAgo = DATEADD(d, -(3 * 365), GetDate())

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM [ISAdminDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
             WHERE [MyTable].[DateTime] < @ThreeYearsAgo)
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRAN 
       INSERT INTO @NextIDs(UniqueID)
        SELECT TOP 1000 UniqueID 
          FROM [ISAdminDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
          WHERE [MyTable].[DateTime] < @ThreeYearsAgo

       INSERT INTO [ISArchive].[dbo].[MyTable] (<Fields>) 
        SELECT (<Fields>) 
        FROM  [ISAdminDB].[dbo].[MyTable] AS a
        INNER JOIN @NextIDs AS b ON a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID

       DELETE [ISAdminDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
       FROM  [ISAdminDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
       INNER JOIN @NextIDs AS b ON a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID 

       DELETE FROM @NextIDs

       COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

@NextIDs  is a table variable.
Here data moved from isadmin mytable to the table variable @NextIDs
then from @NextIDs to isarchive mytable
After that isadmin mytable data is been deleted

Comment: is this answer to your question ?

Comment: So in this code example I would not change where it says UniqueID in any of this code including the join?  Sorry I do not understand yet. Thanks

Comment: To clarify I replaced uniqueID with attachmentid which is the column in my table attachments in my db called production. So whereever I saw uniqueID I replaced it